# Exclude `.js` files but not '.min.js' files from MSBuild publish

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, build, msbuild, msdeploy

Using Visual Studio and MSBuild I would like to be able to exclude all `.js` files and include all `.min.js` files in my deployments.

I know this can be achieved using the file properties in visual studio, but this is not an option as there are far too many files.

---

I have the following `PublishProfile` in my Visual Studio project. Everything works just fine apart from the `<ItemGroup>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Delpoy-Static</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <publishUrl>\\***\wwwroot\***.com\static</publishUrl>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!--This does not work, but gives the idea of what I want to achieve-->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Deploy Exclude="**\*.js" Include="**\*.min.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Can this be achieved using the `PublishProfile`? If so, how?

Comment: I can help you with the MSBuild if you like but let me suggest publish ignore http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/22/web-publishing-a-simpler-way-to-exclude-files-folders-from-being-published.aspx. Can you take a look and let me know if you still need the MSBuild publish profile solution?

Comment: Thanks this looks great, I just need to figure out how I can ignore `.js` files and not `.min.js` files using the syntax available. Does publish ignore follow gitignore syntax strictly?

Comment: Seems not `Error MSB4018: The "ReadPublishIgnoreFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NotSupportedException: The ! operator is not currently supported in publish.ignore
   at InlineCode.ReadPublishIgnoreFile.Execute() in c:\Users\sblowes\AppData\Local\Temp\bzp34wjd.0.cs:line 89
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()`

Comment: Sorry I forgot I never implemented support for !. I've opened an issue to track it https://github.com/ligershark/publish-ignore/issues/8. I've also answered below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <!-- ... -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Minified Include="**\*.min.js" />
      <Maxified Include="**\*.js" Exclude="@(Minified)" />
      <Content Remove="@(Maxified)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Edit:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <!-- ... -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Minified Include="**\*.min.js" />
    <Maxified Include="**\*.js" Exclude="@(Minified)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>@(Maxified);Web.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: sorry I didn't have time to test before the bounty ran out. I have doubled the bounty and will reward within 24h

Comment: Strange, this conflicts with this line `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin;</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>`. When using your code the bin folder is still deployed.

Comment: @Blowsie weird, works fine with an empty web app project, no `bin` deployed, just the `.min.js`. Do you have `DeleteExistingFiles` set? `Exclude*FromDeployment` is even better, no need to muck about with events, see the edit.

Comment: Updated example throws an error `The attribute "Remove" in element <Content> is unrecognized`

Comment: @Blowsie there is no `Remove` attribute in the second non-event based one.

Comment: Bonus question. Is there a target for when a file system web publish has finished?

Comment: @Blowsie you can run `msbuild /v:d WebApplication1.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Foo | find "Target ""After"` to see most of the `After` targets, e.g. `AfterBuild` target would work fine. For empty/default property/target hooks you'd need to read through your imported `.targets`, `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0" && findstr /s /d:Web;WebApplications "$(OnAfter" *.targets`, e.g. `OnAfterWebFileSystemPublish` property should work, i.e. `<OnAfterWebFileSystemPublish>$(OnAfterWebFileSystemPublish);Foo</OnAfterWebFileSystemPublish>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60985/discussion-between-blowsie-and-ilya-kozhevnikov).

Comment: Is this still applicable with VS 2015 when publishing to Azure? I'm finding the non-minified js files are in the temp folder created before pushing to Azure, and then also end up pushed to Azure as well. Js files for my project are in [solution folder][project folder]\wwwroot\js. I've tried paths such as "wwwroot\js\" and just "js\"

Comment: How can i make it to work only if minified file exists?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude files you can place the files to be excluded in the the ExcludeFromPackageFiles item group. In your case you want to take all .js files and exclude all but those that are `*.min.js`. To do that in your .pubxml file add the following in your .pubxml file .

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="js\**\*.js" Exclude="js\**\*min*.js">
      <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note: this snippet assumes that your .js files are in a folder named `js`.

Comment: Thanks, another quick question.  Is there a target for when a file-system web publish has finished?

Comment: Is this still applicable with VS 2015 when publishing to Azure?  I'm finding the non-minified js files are in the temp folder created before pushing to Azure, and then also end up pushed to Azure as well.  Js files for my project are in [solution folder]\[project folder]\wwwroot\js.  I've tried paths such as "wwwroot\js\" and just "js\"

Answer (score 0):

work to me:

1. Edit `.csproj` file
2. Find section `MinifyJavaScriptAndCSS`
3. Edit property `Exclude` in `JS` tag
4. Add directory or files to ignore during publish

```
<Target Name="MinifyJavaScriptAndCSS" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <ItemGroup>

      <!-- Every .js file (exclude *.min.js and *.vsdoc.js files) -->
      <JS Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.js" Exclude="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.min.js;$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*vsdoc.js;" />

      <CSS Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.css" Exclude="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.min.css" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <AjaxMin JsKnownGlobalNames="jQuery,$" JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js" CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".css" />
    <Message Text="[pcv] $(MSBuildProjectName) -&gt; Minified: @(JS)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="[pcv] $(MSBuildProjectName) -&gt; Minified: @(CSS)" Importance="high" />
```