# Exclude .js, include .min.js when publishing to Azure with VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525197/exclude-js-files-but-not-min-js-files-from-msbuild-publish) (seemingly) related SO post, but following the suggestions from both answers [didn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525197/exclude-js-files-but-not-min-js-files-from-msbuild-publish#comment66665915_25629030) [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525197/exclude-js-files-but-not-min-js-files-from-msbuild-publish#comment66665848_25751272), all my js files are getting pushed to Azure (not just the `*.min.js` files from my js folder.)

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?  I could update my gulp script I suppose to read an environment variable ("Development", or "Production") and then delete the source js files conditionally.  It just seems to be better to make the build task function as I wish (especially since it looks doable.)

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Core or ASP.Net MVC 5?

Comment: It is a Core project (MVC 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the gulp route thus far (still interested in the other alternatives if viable.)

Created a new task in my gulpfile...

```
var del = require("del");
gulp.task("remove-non-minjs", function () {
    return del([
        paths.scripts.dest + "**/*.js",
        "!" + paths.scripts.dest + "**/*.min.js"
    ]);
});
```

And then added this to my project.json's prepublish script...

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": [ "gulp default" ],
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "gulp default", "gulp remove-non-minjs" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

I verified it works, but just seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

> Js files for my project are in [solution folder][project folder]\wwwroot\js.

According to the comment you added in the related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525197/exclude-js-files-but-not-min-js-files-from-msbuild-publish) you mentioned, I assumed that your application is Based on ASP.NET Core. As far as I know, we could determine that which file/folder could be included or excluded when publishing your web application by configuring the `publishOptions` section in your project.json file as follows:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "wwwroot/js/**/*.min.js",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/js/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

But, as this [tutorial](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/175#include-structure) mentioned that the exclude patterns have higher priority than the include patterns, hence a file found in both will be excluded. In this situation, you need to configure all the included/excluded files in the includeFiles/excludeFiles node of the `publishOptions`.

According to your requirement, [Using Gulp](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html) would be an ideal approach to achieve it.

Additionally, if your project is an ASP.NET MVC application, you could add the following to your .pubxml file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="wwwroot\js\**\*.js" Exclude="wwwroot\js\**\*.min.js">
    <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
  </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried your latter suggestion (pubxml edit), to no avail.  The non min.js files are still present.

I'm not sure I follow you yet regarding the publishOptions avenue.  Are you saying that should work? Or, are you just suggesting another avenue for me to investigate?

Comment: wwwroot and Views are both mentioned currently in the includes (and all their contents are being published.)  How would adding the more specific path to just the js files I want published affect that?  Would I then need to specify all the rest of the paths (not just rely on the parent being listed?)

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment

Via the Solution Explorer, you can edit the Properties of each file in your project and set the Build Action to NONE.  It looks like you might be able to select multiple files at one time while doing this.

Comment: Would you mind summarizing the link you provided please? to prevent your answer from loosing value if the link breaks and for the ease of the community?

Comment: @Dark there really isn't much more to it other than what I've already summarized in my answer (below the link). I understand the concern for link rot, but this is a link to a technical document on Microsoft.com - not just a random site.  They usually try to permalink these things...

Comment: It's ok it's not that your answer is wrong, however it's more than just a possible broken or aged link. The thing is that the SE network should be documented and self-explanatory by itself, so people don't have to go search other resources or info in other places (therefore losing time, etc.). Some people may not have access to outside networks, or well access it via some app, that's why it is better to write as much as possible about the relevant parts of the link you share.